# Why can't I use parentheses with import statement?

Tags: python, import

`Backslash` can be used as one-line codes are too long.

like:

> `import` sentence

```py
import os, sys, datetime, pathlib, enum, string, itertools, functools

import os, \
       time, \
       datetime,\
       sys
```

> `from ... import ...` sentence

```py
from os import path, pipe, pardir

from os import  path, \
                pipe, \
                pardir

from os import  (path,
                pipe,
                pardir)
```

My question is why

```
import (os, 
       time,
      datetime)
```

doesn't work as

```
from os import  (path,
                pipe,
                pardir)
```

works?

Comment: The [import](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html) statement.

Comment: The answer to the last question is found in the formal grammar for [import statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) - note the lack of parentheses on the bare `import` statement, and that the parentheses is supported subsequent to the `from ... import` statement.

Comment: Python doesn't have `()` for `import` in its grammary. And [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests to put every import in separated line as more readable. See [imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Answer (score -1):

OS module provides a portable way of using operating system dependent functionality.

import (os, time,datetime) 
  here you are importing three models at a time,but python compiler understand this

from os import  (path,pipe,pardir)
   here we are using from os import ...means it searches the that packages are installed in site packeges are not if installed no error otherwise  throug's a exception